# get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk': django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

i'm creating like button for my django blog i import api to use ajex from django rest frameworks but i'm getting error in that the error is get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk' django

## view.py

```
class PostLikeToggle(RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
          obj = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=kwargs['pk'])
          url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
          user = self.request.user
          if user.is_authenticated:
             if user in obj.likes.all():
                obj.likes.remove(user)
             else:
                obj.likes.add(user)
          return url_

   from rest_framework.views import APIView
   from rest_framework.response import Response
   from rest_framework import authentication, permissions
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User

   class PostLikeApiToggle(APIView):

        authentication_classes = [authentication.SessionAuthentication]
        permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

        def get(self, request, format=None):
            usernames = [user.username for user in User.objects.all()]
            return Response(usernames)

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
            obj = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=kwargs['pk'])
            url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
            user = self.request.user
            updated = False
            liked =False
            if user.is_authenticated:
               if user in obj.likes.all():
                  liked = False
                  obj.likes.remove(user)
               else:
                   liked = True
                   obj.likes.add(user)
            updated = True
            data = {
                   "updated":updated,
                    "liked":liked
                   }

           return Response(data)
```

## urls.py

```
    path('blog/<int:pk>/like/', PostLikeToggle.as_view(),name='Like-Toggle'),
    path('blog/api/<int:pk>/like/', PostLikeApiToggle.as_view(),name='Like-Api-Toggle'),
```

## models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     likes =models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,related_name='post_likes')
     content = models.TextField()
     img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics',blank=True)
     time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('LoveTravel-Details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def get_like_url(self):
       return reverse('Like-Toggle', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def get_api_like_url(self):
       return reverse('Like-Api-Toggle', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

can someone please help me get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk' in that error

Comment: How are you calling ```get_redirect_url``` function??

Comment: Can you correct your indenting? It's very hard to read like this.

Comment: with Redirectview

Comment: is it ok now? @Exelian

Comment: No, it is not. See models.py

Comment: now its ok or not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error is quite explicit. The `get` method is missing an argument.
In order to fix that:

```
class PostLikeApiToggle(APIView):
    ...
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
```

Why did you get that error ?

Your `urls.py` defines the path as `'blog/<int:pk>/like/'`. Django will resolve that url and call the view's method - get in your case - with the group names/values as keyword arguments -  refer to [the point 4 of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) for more details about how Django processes requests.